# How to create query for selecting many to many elements

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I have entity that has on many-to-many connection:

- Entity - main object
- Clients - has many-to-many with Entity via "entity_clients" table

config in .yml

```
manyToMany:
  clients:
    targetEntity: Client
    joinTable:
      name: entity_clients
      joinColumns:
        taskpack_id:
          referencedColumnName: id
      inverseJoinColumns:
        client_id:
          referencedColumnName: id
```

I have **Entity** element and I want to get **query** clients attached to it.
Clients i can select:

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entity = $em->getRepository('TestGroupBundle:Entity')->find($id);
    $clients = $entity->getClients();
```

But I need query how to select this elements. I try to write query but nothing like this:

```
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('c')
            ->from('TestGroupBundle:Entity', 't')
            ->join('t.clients', 'c')
            ->andWhere('t.id = :id')
            ->setParameter('id', $id);
```

But i get error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col -1 near 'SELECT c FROM': Error: Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias.
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add the initial entity to the select.

```
->select('t, c')
```